# host ASP CORE 2.1 on local IIS windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP CORE 2.1 written in c# website that works perfect in IIS express and hosted on azure. BUT when I try to host it myself on local IIS or just run it from Visual Studio in IIS (not express) it doesn't work. I get 
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
have been banging my head for 2 days and I am no closer. Please help.

To add detail:

Program looks like this (use kestrel I added today)

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .Build();
}
```

Start up like this

```
  public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
}
```

IIS like this:
[image]

App Pool like this:
[image]

Think its security related. Last night I created and trusted local dev certificate...not sure I did it right buts its there...do I have to somehow tell my website to look for that specifically?

As I said, IIS express perfect, Azure perfect so I just dont know what else to do. Im asking on here as I am stumped, not to be lazy. I have installed the IIS software, re started, installed the correct runtime host software, restarted.

Additional, found this is the log:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
>         Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
>
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
>         Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
>
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>         No XML encryptor configured. Key {cfc3f092-a4fc-4b5b-9a64-e7d35b02feff} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
>   Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: D:\IIS\SALUSUAVWEBAPP
>   Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:6396
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>         Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Am looking into this right now...is that the reason or is it just a warning about something that isn't my real issue?

Comment: And what did you actually do in your computer for it to work? Did you follow [the documentation on hosting ASP.NET Core on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)? What exact steps did you take? Also, even Microsoft says that attempting to run ASP.NET Core on IIS from Visual Studio doesn't work correctly

Comment: I followed those steps. If I cant host in IIS do you know how I can host it locally so that I can test it from my machine and also get someone else to test not on my machine? it will save me a fortune in azure costs until Im ready for it to go live

Comment: How much can it save you if you can have it on a *free* instance on Azure? And you certainly didn't follow every step as those work just fine.

Comment: Im pretty sure I followed every step, a few times now. I have a large database so hosting on azure is expensive, I have a development licence so I can use that for testing and development locally.

Comment: As so many others (including me) can have ASP.NET Core running locally on IIS following Microsoft documentation, so if you don't plan to show more details by editing your question, it is impossible to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the answer was the bindings...I didn't have https set up...
documentation didn't show that and due to a lack of experience in this area I didn't think about that...own fault. Anyway...going to go read all about https and certificates as that's my next nightmare...how do I sort that out so people can call me...

[image]